# Setting array values without knowing its type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have an array of MyType s in an object similar to the setup below, I want to be able to set the value of an index on myObject as it is, I cannot change the declaration of MyFunction.

```
/*...*/
MyType [] myTypedArray = new MyType[100];
MyFunction(myTypedArray);
/*...*/

function MyFunction(object myObject)
{
    myObject[0] = new MyType();
}
```

This, obviously, doesn't work but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.  I cannot cannot use templates/generics it has to be all using reflection.

Note that I have to have myObjectArray, initially, as an "object" as this is how I receive it.  I cannot do the initial cast to a object[].  I have tried casting myObjectArray to object[] and it doesn't work.

I also do not have access to MyType as a static type, only runtime.

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: How can you new() it if you don't have the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the object to an `Array` and call [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.setvalue.aspx) on it, for a completely non-object-specific way of doing it. This'll box & unbox value types as appropriate & do all the necessary array type checking.

Answer (score 4):

Declare `myObjectArray` as an array of `object`s:

```
object[] myObjectArray = myTypedArray;
myObjectArray[0] = new MyType(); // okay to go!
```

Alternatively, if for some reason `myObjectArray` must be an `object` you can say:

```
((object[])myObjectArray)[0] = new MyType();
```

These are smelly though. And beware of [array covariance in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)!

Here's an implementation along the lines that you seem to be looking for:

```
void AddToArray(object array, int index) {
    if(array == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    Type arrayType = array.GetType();
    if(!arrayType.IsArray) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("array must be an Array");
    }

    (Array)asArray = (Array)array;
    if (index < 0 || index >= asArray.Length) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
    }
    object newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(elementType);
    asArray.SetValue(newInstance, index);
}
```

Invoke as:

```
AddToArray(myObjectArray, 0);
```

This assumes that `elementType` has a parameterless constructor. There are ways around this, but this should be enough to get you started. This method also probably needs a better name.

Again, this code is very smelly. I would suggest taking a step back and seeing if you can solve your problem using strongly-typed code.

Comment: I have clarified question, I have no control over how I originally see myObjectArray - it comes in as an object not an object[]

Comment: @Chris: See comment beginning with "Alternatively, if for some reason...".

Comment: Thanks Jason.  However I tried something similar and I got an error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean[]' to type 'System.Object[]'."

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, that's because `bool` is a value type. The CLR will never let you cast an array where the elements are value types to any other array type. So `string[] strings = new string[n]; object o = strings; object[] array = (object[])o;` is legal but `bool[] bools = new bool[n]; object o = bools; object[] array = (object[])o;` is not.

Comment: Any idea what I can do then? The array type could be anything? (Note this is for my own serialization stuff)

Comment: You can use the Array.SetValue method directly, rather than casting to object[] (see my response below). This will work for all arrays, including ones of value types

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
DayOfWeek[] myTypedArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
                               .OfType<DayOfWeek>().ToArray();
object myObject = myTypedArray;

object[] myObjectArray =   // from object to object[]
        (myObject as Array ?? new object[0]).OfType<object>().ToArray();

Type type = myObjectArray[0].GetType(); // unbox type
myObjectArray[0] = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // create another instance
```

Note you'll lose type safety.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need a cast to `object[]`:

```
((object[])myObjectArray)[0] = new MyType();
```

Comment: OP says he can't cast to object[]

Answer (score 0):

`((MyType[])myObjectArray)[0] = new MyType();` perhaps?